# Mortgage payment calculation does not reach to zero ending balance when interest rate is variable

Tags: python

I have implemented [fixed rate mortgage in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70142979/fixed-rate-mortgage-in-python) for fixed interest rate with no problem, but I do have a problem when implementing this for variable interest rates (ARM7/1: interest rate is fixed for first 7 years and it changes every year, average of last 52 weeks), I have the modified the code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy_financial as npf
from datetime import date

movingRates = [0.08033, # year 2001
               0.08033, # year 2002
               0.08033, # year 2003
               0.08033, # year 2004
               0.08033, # year 2005
               0.08033, # year 2006
               0.08033, # year 2007
               0.06337, # year 2008
               0.06027, # year 2009
               0.05037, # year 2010
               0.04690, # year 2011
               0.04448, # year 2012
               0.03658, # year 2013
               0.03976, # year 2014
               0.04162, # year 2015
               0.03851, # year 2016
               0.03654, # year 2017
               0.03990, # year 2018
               0.04545, # year 2019
               0.03936  # year 2020 
              ]
               
ARM71Rates = np.repeat(movingRates, 12)   # convert yearly rates to montly repetitions

def fixed_rate_mortgage(interest: float, years: int, payments_year: int, mortgage: int, start_date: str):
    periods = years * payments_year
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(1, periods+1))
    df["Date"] = pd.date_range(start_date, periods=periods, freq='MS', name='Payment Date').date
    df["Interest Rate"] = interest
    df["Payment"]        = -1 * npf.pmt( df["Interest Rate"]/payments_year, periods, mortgage)
    df["Interest Paid"]  = -1 * npf.ipmt(df["Interest Rate"]/payments_year, df.index, periods, mortgage)
    df["Principal Paid"] = -1 * npf.ppmt(df["Interest Rate"]/payments_year, df.index, periods, mortgage)
    df['Ending Balance'] = mortgage - df['Principal Paid'].cumsum()
    df[df['Ending Balance'] < 0] = 0
    total_loan = loan + df['Interest Paid'].sum()
    print(f"\nTotal of the loan is: ${total_loan:,.2f}.\n")
    return df


interest = ARM71Rates
years = 20
payments_year = 12

loan = 1000000

start_date = "2001-01-01"
year, month, day = map(int, start_date.split("-"))
start_date = date(year, month, day)

mydf = fixed_rate_mortgage(interest, years, payments_year, loan, start_date)
```

The output was not as I expected, i.e. the remaining balanced does not reach to zero at the end of 240 months. Could you help which code step I missed something. Thank you very much.

```
    Date  Interest Rate      Payment  Interest Paid  Principal Paid  \
1    2020-01-01        0.08033  8384.950096    6694.166667     1690.783430   
2    2020-02-01        0.08033  8384.950096    6682.848281     1702.101816   
3    2020-03-01        0.08033  8384.950096    6671.454127     1713.495969   
4    2020-04-01        0.08033  8384.950096    6659.983700     1724.966397   
5    2020-05-01        0.08033  8384.950096    6648.436487     1736.513609   
..          ...            ...          ...            ...             ...   
236  2039-08-01        0.03936  6026.132814      97.863499     5928.269315   
237  2039-09-01        0.03936  6026.132814      78.418776     5947.714038   
238  2039-10-01        0.03936  6026.132814      58.910274     5967.222540   
239  2039-11-01        0.03936  6026.132814      39.337784     5986.795030   
240  2039-12-01        0.03936  6026.132814      19.701096     6006.431718   

     Ending Balance  
1     998309.216570  
2     996607.114754  
3     994893.618785  
4     993168.652389  
5     991432.138780  
..              ...  
236   105257.834459  
237    99310.120421  
238    93342.897881  
239    87356.102850  
240    81349.671132  

[240 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: I don't know this library well, but note if you run this code, except using a rate of 0.03936 for *every* month of the mortage (not only the last 12), then the payment for every month is 6026.13. That's the same as the payment for the last 12 months in your example, which looks wrong. Looks like when you give numpy_financial a rate schedule, it doesn't do a proper ARM calculation: instead it calculates the payment for every month *as if that month's rate applied for the whole mortgage*, which isn't right.  The docs don't seem clear about whether this case is intended to be supported or not.

Comment: yes the library may be the problem, and may not be supporting variable rates, Thanks:)